# customize pivot header in wp8.1

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, pivot

i am trying to implement the solution as shown in the diagram below. i am unable to get into the visual state of pivot header. By doing so i want to attach the line as shown in diagram with the respective pivot header. the line should move or appear as the person swipes to the next pivot header. any idea.?
        [image]
code snippet:

```
     <Grid>
      <Pivot x:Uid="Pivot" Title="MY APPLICATION" x:Name="pivot" CommonNavigationTransitionInfo.IsStaggerElement="True">
        <!--Pivot item one-->
        <PivotItem
            x:Uid="PivotItem1"
            Margin="19,14.5,0,0"
            Header="first"
            DataContext="{Binding FirstGroup}"
            d:DataContext="{Binding Groups[0], Source={d:DesignData Source=/DataModel/SampleData.json, Type=data:SampleDataSource}}"
            CommonNavigationTransitionInfo.IsStaggerElement="True">
            <TextBlock Text="Hello 1 " FontSize="32" Foreground="White" />

        </PivotItem>

        <!--Pivot item two-->
        <PivotItem
            x:Uid="PivotItem2"
            Margin="19,14.5,0,0"
            Header="second"
            DataContext="{Binding SecondGroup}"
            d:DataContext="{Binding Groups[1], Source={d:DesignData Source=/DataModel/SampleData.json, Type=data:SampleDataSource}}">
            <!--Double line list no text wrapping-->
            <TextBlock Text="Hello 2 " FontSize="32" Foreground="White" />
        </PivotItem>

        <!--Pivot item three-->
        <PivotItem
            x:Uid="PivotItem3"
            Margin="19,14.5,0,0"
            Header="third"
            DataContext="{Binding SecondGroup}"
            d:DataContext="{Binding Groups[1], Source={d:DesignData Source=/DataModel/SampleData.json, Type=data:SampleDataSource}}">
            <TextBlock Text="Hello 3 " FontSize="32" Foreground="White" />
        </PivotItem>


    </Pivot>
    <Rectangle x:Name="rectangle" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="5" Margin="20,104,0,0" Stroke="Orange" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="94" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
        <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
            <CompositeTransform/>
        </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
    </Rectangle>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi try this code hope so it will be helpful for you

I have taken this pivot for demo

```
<phone:Pivot Style="{StaticResource PivotStyle1}" >
            <phone:Pivot.TitleTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid />
                </DataTemplate>
            </phone:Pivot.TitleTemplate>
            <!--Pivot item one-->
            <phone:PivotItem Header="item1">
                <Grid Background="#FFE60202" />
            </phone:PivotItem>

            <!--Pivot item two-->
            <phone:PivotItem Header="item2">
                <Grid Background="#FF0CC2CB" />
            </phone:PivotItem>
        </phone:Pivot>
```

Now Apply this style to create design like you have given into Image.

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="PivotHeaderItemStyle1" TargetType="Primitives:PivotHeaderItem">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="21,0,1,0"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Primitives:PivotHeaderItem">
                        <Grid Margin="0">
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Unselected"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter"/>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="border">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="#FFE28930" BorderThickness="1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Opacity="{StaticResource PhonePivotUnselectedItemOpacity}" Margin="15,0"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="PivotStyle1" TargetType="phone:Pivot">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <Grid/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="phone:Pivot">
                        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Grid.RowSpan="3"/>
                            <ContentControl x:Name="TitleElement" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding TitleTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Title}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="24,17,0,-7" Style="{StaticResource PivotTitleStyle}"/>
                            <Primitives:PivotHeadersControl x:Name="HeadersListElement" Grid.Row="1" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource PivotHeaderItemStyle1}" Foreground="#FF107AD3" FontSize="33.333"/>
                            <ItemsPresenter x:Name="PivotItemPresenter" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Grid.Row="2"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.FontFamily>
        <StaticResource ResourceKey="PhoneFontFamilyNormal"/>
    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.FontFamily>
    <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.FontSize>
        <StaticResource ResourceKey="PhoneFontSizeNormal"/>
    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.FontSize>
    <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Foreground>
        <StaticResource ResourceKey="PhoneForegroundBrush"/>
    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Foreground>
```

Comment: thanks bro but it gives an error .  its a wp8.1 app . And i am using visual studio 2013 update5.  error is on tag PivotHeadersControl ..... it says that the tag is not supported in windows phone project . rest of the code is fine .

Comment: Sorry , I have read that you have tag this question in Windows-phone-8 so I think its WP8.1 SilverLight App. If it is WP8.1 SilverLight App than it will surly work if still getting error please let me know.

Comment: no problem bro ...  i have tried the ur code in wp8.1 silverlight too but it gives error too. If u could help in providing similar snippet for wp8.1 normal app . that would be great. thanks once again

Comment: Maulik bro if u could help in applying it in Wp8.1 app because getting lots of issue .

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same problem today. Found the basic idea from [Justin XL's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31799121/2898399) Here is the solution that currently worked for UWP. Hope this helps someone

```
<Style TargetType="PivotHeaderItem">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemFontSize}" />
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemFontFamily}" />
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemThemeFontWeight}" />
            <Setter Property="CharacterSpacing" Value="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemCharacterSpacing}" />            
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#AAAAAA" />
            <!-- original value {ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseMediumBrush} -->
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemMargin}" />
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="48" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="PivotHeaderItem">
                        <Grid x:Name="Grid" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="0,0,0,2">
                            <Grid.Resources>
                                <Style x:Key="BaseContentPresenterStyle" TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                                    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI" />
                                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="SemiBold" />
                                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15" />
                                    <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
                                    <Setter Property="LineStackingStrategy" Value="MaxHeight" />
                                    <Setter Property="TextLineBounds" Value="Full" />
                                    <Setter Property="OpticalMarginAlignment" Value="TrimSideBearings" />
                                </Style>
                                <Style x:Key="BodyContentPresenterStyle" TargetType="ContentPresenter" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseContentPresenterStyle}">
                                    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemFontFamily}" />
                                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemThemeFontWeight}" />
                                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemFontSize}" />
                                </Style>
                            </Grid.Resources>
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                                    <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                        <VisualTransition From="Unselected" To="UnselectedLocked" GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.33" />
                                        <VisualTransition From="UnselectedLocked" To="Unselected" GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.33" />
                                    </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseMediumLowBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Unselected" />
                                    <VisualState x:Name="UnselectedLocked">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenterTranslateTransform" Storyboard.TargetProperty="X" Duration="0" To="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemLockedTranslation}" />
                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Duration="0" To="0" />
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Black" />                                                
                                                <!-- original value {ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush} -->
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Grid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="OrangeRed" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Grid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightTransparentBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="UnselectedPointerOver">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseMediumHighBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Grid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightTransparentBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="SelectedPointerOver">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseMediumHighBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Grid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightTransparentBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="UnselectedPressed">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseMediumHighBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Grid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="White" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Grid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightTransparentBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="SelectedPressed">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseMediumHighBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Grid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightTransparentBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                                <ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
                                    <TranslateTransform x:Name="ContentPresenterTranslateTransform" />
                                </ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
                            </ContentPresenter>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Now this being keyless style you will need to add this inside the same page. Here I have updated and added a BorderBrush with a thickness of 2 at the bottom.
This gets updated as per the visual state needed. have currently updated it for `Selected` and `UnselectedPressed`