# customizing pivot header by adding a line in wp8.1

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1, pivot

i am trying to implement the solution as shown in the diagram below. i am unable to get into the visual state of pivot header. By doing so i want to attach the line as shown in diagram with the respective pivot header. the line should move or appear as the person swipes to the next pivot header. any idea.?[image]

code snippet:

```
 <Grid>
  <Pivot x:Uid="Pivot" Title="MY APPLICATION" x:Name="pivot" CommonNavigationTransitionInfo.IsStaggerElement="True">
    <!--Pivot item one-->
    <PivotItem
        x:Uid="PivotItem1"
        Margin="19,14.5,0,0"
        Header="first"
        DataContext="{Binding FirstGroup}"
        d:DataContext="{Binding Groups[0], Source={d:DesignData Source=/DataModel/SampleData.json, Type=data:SampleDataSource}}"
        CommonNavigationTransitionInfo.IsStaggerElement="True">
        <TextBlock Text="Hello 1 " FontSize="32" Foreground="White" />

    </PivotItem>

    <!--Pivot item two-->
    <PivotItem
        x:Uid="PivotItem2"
        Margin="19,14.5,0,0"
        Header="second"
        DataContext="{Binding SecondGroup}"
        d:DataContext="{Binding Groups[1], Source={d:DesignData Source=/DataModel/SampleData.json, Type=data:SampleDataSource}}">
        <!--Double line list no text wrapping-->
        <TextBlock Text="Hello 2 " FontSize="32" Foreground="White" />
    </PivotItem>

    <!--Pivot item three-->
    <PivotItem
        x:Uid="PivotItem3"
        Margin="19,14.5,0,0"
        Header="third"
        DataContext="{Binding SecondGroup}"
        d:DataContext="{Binding Groups[1], Source={d:DesignData Source=/DataModel/SampleData.json, Type=data:SampleDataSource}}">
        <TextBlock Text="Hello 3 " FontSize="32" Foreground="White" />
    </PivotItem>


</Pivot>
<Rectangle x:Name="rectangle" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="5" Margin="20,104,0,0" Stroke="Orange" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="94" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
    <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
        <CompositeTransform/>
    </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
</Rectangle>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [customize pivot header in wp8.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31716203/customize-pivot-header-in-wp8-1)

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same problem today. Found the basic idea from [Justin XL's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31799121/2898399) Here is the solution that currently worked for UWP. Hope this helps someone

```
<Style TargetType="PivotHeaderItem">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemFontSize}" />
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemFontFamily}" />
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemThemeFontWeight}" />
            <Setter Property="CharacterSpacing" Value="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemCharacterSpacing}" />            
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#AAAAAA" />
            <!-- original value {ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseMediumBrush} -->
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemMargin}" />
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="48" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="PivotHeaderItem">
                        <Grid x:Name="Grid" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="0,0,0,2">
                            <Grid.Resources>
                                <Style x:Key="BaseContentPresenterStyle" TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                                    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI" />
                                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="SemiBold" />
                                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15" />
                                    <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
                                    <Setter Property="LineStackingStrategy" Value="MaxHeight" />
                                    <Setter Property="TextLineBounds" Value="Full" />
                                    <Setter Property="OpticalMarginAlignment" Value="TrimSideBearings" />
                                </Style>                                    
                            </Grid.Resources>
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                                    <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                        <VisualTransition From="Unselected" To="UnselectedLocked" GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.33" />
                                        <VisualTransition From="UnselectedLocked" To="Unselected" GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.33" />
                                    </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseMediumLowBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Unselected" />
                                    <VisualState x:Name="UnselectedLocked">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenterTranslateTransform" Storyboard.TargetProperty="X" Duration="0" To="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemLockedTranslation}" />
                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Duration="0" To="0" />
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Black" />                                                
                                                <!-- original value {ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush} -->
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Grid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="OrangeRed" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Grid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightTransparentBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="UnselectedPointerOver">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseMediumHighBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Grid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightTransparentBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="SelectedPointerOver">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseMediumHighBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Grid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightTransparentBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="UnselectedPressed">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseMediumHighBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Grid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="White" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Grid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightTransparentBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="SelectedPressed">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseMediumHighBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Grid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightTransparentBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                                <ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
                                    <TranslateTransform x:Name="ContentPresenterTranslateTransform" />
                                </ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
                            </ContentPresenter>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Now this being keyless style you will need to add this inside the same page. Here I have updated and added a BorderBrush with a thickness of 2 at the bottom.
This gets updated as per the visual state needed. have currently updated it for `Selected` and `UnselectedPressed`.
Since this is the same question but couldnt mark it as duplicate as no answer was marked in the linked question.