# Overriding Pivot header foreground brushes in UWP app (Win 10 RTM SDK)

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, win-universal-app, windows-10, uwp

I'm trying to override the Pivot header foreground theme brushes, but no matter what I do the UWP app just ignores it.

Just to be clear, this question is about the UWP Pivot control, not the Win (Phone) 8.1 one. I've used the theme brush override method in a 8.1 app and it worked perfectly. But I can't seem to be able to do the same for a UWP Pivot.

I looked for the respective brushes in generic.xaml (and in the Properties pane under Brushes -> System Brush Resources), which are PivotHeaderForegroundSelectedBrush and PivotHeaderForegroundUnselectedBrush in a UWP app, and added them to my resource dictionary in app.xaml, but unlike the other system brushes, the Pivot ones aren't overridden for some reason.

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="SystemControlForegroundAccentBrush" Color="Gray"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="SystemControlBackgroundAccentBrush" Color="Gray"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="SystemColorControlAccentBrush" Color="Gray"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="PivotHeaderForegroundSelectedBrush" Color="Green" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="PivotHeaderForegroundUnselectedBrush" Color="Red"/>
```

I know other ways to change the header foreground color, but that might involve converters or extra code behind, which I'd rather not use to be honest if i can do it in a clean way. I tried editing the default Pivot style, but I don't see anywhere where I can add/edit a Foreground property for the header items in the default Pivot style.

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Interestingly, the `Foreground` property of the `PivotItemStyle` controls the foreground color of the *content* within the `PivotItem`, not the *header* of it. And there's no way to modify the color of the *header* within the style.

You might be able to find the corresponding color resources and modify them to achieve what you want, but here's a more flexible and pure xaml way -

The `Pivot` control actually has a `HeaderTemplate` which allows you to fully customise your `PivotItem` *headers*. See the following code sample, all the *headers* should have the **Teal** color.

```
<Grid>
    <Pivot Title="Pivot">
        <Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Foreground="Teal" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Pivot.HeaderTemplate>

        <PivotItem Header="My first header">
            <Grid/>
        </PivotItem>
    </Pivot>
</Grid>
```

---

**Update**

So here is a better way.

I used the new *Live Visual Tree* tool in *Visual Studio* to help locate the actual header element. It's a control called `PivotHeaderItem`. So turns out, all the styling is defined within this control.

I then had to go to [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299142.aspx) and grabbed the full style of this control (Blend didn't work).

As you can see within the style, the control has a default `Foreground` of `{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseMediumBrush}` and within the *visual states*, this `Foreground` gets changed to `{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}` when the *state* goes to `Selected`. I've changed them to `Red` and `Green` to make them more obvious.

```
<Style TargetType="PivotHeaderItem">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemFontSize}" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemFontFamily}" />
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemThemeFontWeight}" />
    <Setter Property="CharacterSpacing" Value="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemCharacterSpacing}" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" /> <!-- original value {ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseMediumBrush} -->
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemMargin}" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="48" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="PivotHeaderItem">
                <Grid x:Name="Grid" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <Grid.Resources>
                        <Style x:Key="BaseContentPresenterStyle" TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI" />
                            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="SemiBold" />
                            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15" />
                            <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
                            <Setter Property="LineStackingStrategy" Value="MaxHeight" />
                            <Setter Property="TextLineBounds" Value="Full" />
                            <Setter Property="OpticalMarginAlignment" Value="TrimSideBearings" />
                        </Style>
                        <Style x:Key="BodyContentPresenterStyle" TargetType="ContentPresenter" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseContentPresenterStyle}">
                            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemFontFamily}" />
                            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemThemeFontWeight}" />
                            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemFontSize}" />
                        </Style>
                    </Grid.Resources>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualTransition From="Unselected" To="UnselectedLocked" GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.33" />
                                <VisualTransition From="UnselectedLocked" To="Unselected" GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.33" />
                            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseMediumLowBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unselected" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="UnselectedLocked">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenterTranslateTransform" Storyboard.TargetProperty="X" Duration="0" To="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemLockedTranslation}" />
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Duration="0" To="0" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Green" /> <!-- original value {ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush} -->
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Grid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightTransparentBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="UnselectedPointerOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseMediumHighBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Grid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightTransparentBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="SelectedPointerOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseMediumHighBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Grid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightTransparentBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="UnselectedPressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseMediumHighBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Grid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightTransparentBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="SelectedPressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseMediumHighBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Grid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightTransparentBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                        <ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
                            <TranslateTransform x:Name="ContentPresenterTranslateTransform" />
                        </ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
                    </ContentPresenter>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

With this, you should now be able to fully customise your pivot headers! :)

Comment: Thank you for the answer Justin :), but I already know that method. My problem lies in the fact that all headers get the same color. I want to have a different color (or opacity rather) for the selected and unselected headers just like the regular Pivot. The easiest way in a 8.1 app was to use the method I posted above, but if I use your suggested method, I'd have to use a converter or code-behind to change the opacity.color of the header items.

Comment: @Abdousamad ohh you are right! Let me have a think about it n get back to you.

Comment: I wasn't familiar with the Live Visual Tree method. Thanks! :D

Comment: Where is this PivotItemHeader to which this style has to be applied?

Comment: @ac-lab it's a Keyless style which means it needs to be placed inside either App.xaml, a resource dictionary or the page where the Pivot is used.

Comment: @JustinXL I put it (exactly same code you wrote above) in the page where the pivot is used but I don't get the desired effects, ie, selected pivot header as green.

Comment: @ac-lab You must have done something wrong. You should post a question with your code.

Comment: @Justin How do you get that PivotHeaderItem style from Blend? It seems I only can have an empty style :( Thx

Comment: @Fabrice see the 3rd paragraph in the **Update** section of the answer. :) I couldn't get it from Blend either.

Comment: @Justin Sorry I didn't see that :) Thank you for you answer.

Comment: Hi I want to create two PivotHeaderItem style one keyless and one with key can you please tell me how to apply a style with key for PivotHeaderItem.

Comment: With the first part of your answer (the XAML) how would you then change the color programmatically with C#?

Comment: @AdrianK can you create a brush property and use it with data binding?

Comment: Ah, maybe. I posted it as a new Q:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37669908/how-to-access-pivot-header-template-dynamically-i-e-using-c

Answer (score 1):

you can also set each pivot item's header to its own unique color

```
<Pivot>
    <PivotItem>
        <PivotItem.Header>
            <PivotItemHeader Content="Header 1" Foreground="Magenta"/>
        </PivotItem.Header>
        <Grid>
            <!-- pivot item content here -->
        </Grid>
    </PivotItem>
    <PivotItem>
        <PivotItem.Header>
            <PivotItemHeader Content="Header 2" Foreground="Cyan"/>
        </PivotItem.Header>
        <Grid>
            <!-- pivot item content here -->
        </Grid>
    </PivotItem>
</Pivot>
```