# Change style of PivotItemHeader

Tags: xaml, uwp, windows-10, win-universal-app

I currently try to change the visual style of my pivot control in UWP.

I would like to change the plain default style of "just text" to something like this:

[image]

This is just an example I quickly found on the web. But it is a good representation of what I want to achieve. 
I would like to make the pivot items to look like they are tabs.
They should be visibly seperated from another and when one of the items is selected I want to make it visually stand out from the others.

I'm really new to styling controls. I actually just started to read about it yesterday. But it really helps to make an app visually interesting instead of just the plain default styles.

I would really appreciate some help or guidance here :)

Greetings :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can modify the [PivotHeaderItem default style](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299142.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to implement the effect. Here is also a similar thread that describes how to achieve it : [Pivot Header style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36334021/pivot-header-style)

Please note that: the [PivotHeaderItem default style](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299142.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) is based on the Windows Software Development Kit (SDK) for Windows 10, Version 1511 (Windows SDK version 10.0.10586.0). If your app target on other version, the styles and resources may be have different values. But the approach to implement the effect is similar. You can find the corresponding source in the path of your Windows SDK installation such as: 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\DesignTime\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\UAP\10.0.16299.0\Generic.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to the right post. That actually helped me a lot :)