# How to access Pivot Header Template Dynamically (i.e. using C#)

Tags: uwp

As per @Justin XL's answer to this question ([Overriding Pivot header foreground brushes in UWP app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31797875/overriding-pivot-header-foreground-brushes-in-uwp-app-win-10-rtm-sdk)) you can style the Pivot Header in XAML (as per his code, below).

Having done this in XAML, how would you then programmatically change something (e.g. the Foreground) dynamically using C#?

```
<Grid>
    <Pivot Title="Pivot">
        <Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Foreground="Teal" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Pivot.HeaderTemplate>

        <PivotItem Header="My first header">
            <Grid/>
        </PivotItem>
    </Pivot>
</Grid>
```

Update: Currently I only have 3 pivot items (tabs) and they are all set in the XAML, but the user can change the style (Foreground & Background) - updating the UI to match their changes is simple enough - except for the pivot headers.

Comment: One way would be trying to get them individually using the VisualTree given parent as Pivot! Though I'm not sure this is the best solution

Comment: Sorry been busy. So what stops you from doing data binding?

Comment: Lol - I've been busy too - this issue has fallen down the priority list for now.  In answer to your question: probably nothing except my lack of skill / time to remind myself how to bind :)