# UWP Pivot change color of tabs

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I am trying to do an App with Tabs in UWP. I am using `Pivot` control for the tabs and I have a new `Pivot` in the tabs. My goal is to set the background of `Tab1`, `Tab1.1`,`Tab1.2` to green and the back  of `Tab2`,`Tab2.1`,`Tab2.2` to blue

```
<Pivot >
  <PivotItem Header="Tab1">  //background must be green
     <Pivot>
        <PivotItem Header="Tab1.1" />  //background must be green
        <PivotItem Header="Tab1.2" />  //background must be green
     </Pivot>
  </PivotItem>

  <PivotItem Header="Tab2">  //background must be blue
     <Pivot>
        <PivotItem Header="Tab2.1" />  //background must be blue
        <PivotItem Header="Tab2.2" />  //background must be blue
     </Pivot>
  </PivotItem>
</Pivot>
```

I stumbled upon this post [Overriding Pivot header foreground brushes in UWP app (Win 10 RTM SDK)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31797875/overriding-pivot-header-foreground-brushes-in-uwp-app-win-10-rtm-sdk) and I pasted the code `<Style TargetType="PivotHeaderItem">...` in my App.xaml. From the post I understand that I can customize the looks of my tabs, but I cannot figure out how to do it. The problem is that if I make some changes to the colors they apply to all tabs.

Could you please help me, I am new to this stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adjust the header directly, which is an object, but rendered as a control.  Here's an example:

```
<Pivot Background="Red">
    <PivotItem Background="Green">
        <PivotItem.Header>
            <Grid Background="Green">
                <TextBlock Text="Tab1" />
            </Grid>
        </PivotItem.Header>
        <Pivot>
            <PivotItem Header="Tab1.1" />
            <PivotItem Header="Tab1.2" />
        </Pivot>
    </PivotItem>

    <PivotItem Background="Blue">
        <PivotItem.Header>
            <Grid Background="Blue">
                <TextBlock Text="Tab1" />
            </Grid>
        </PivotItem.Header>
        <Pivot>
            <PivotItem Header="Tab2.1" />
            <PivotItem Header="Tab2.2" />
        </Pivot>
    </PivotItem>
</Pivot>
```

[image]
[image]

Alternately you can edit the style of each `PivotItem`.
Default Style:
*NOTE:  I used Expression Blend to pull easily pull out the default Style / Templates for editing.  I recommend giving Expression Blend the opportunity to assist you here since this is one of the things it was meant for and best at.*

```
<Style x:Key="PivotItemStyle1" TargetType="PivotItem">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource PivotItemBackground}"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="{ThemeResource PivotItemMargin}"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="PivotItem">
                <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="Pivot">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Right"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Left"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Center"/>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

You can also edit the `Style` of the `Pivot` itself.

```
<ControlTemplate x:Name="ScrollViewerScrollBarlessTemplate" TargetType="ScrollViewer">
    <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
        <ScrollContentPresenter x:Name="ScrollContentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
<Style x:Key="PivotStyle1" TargetType="Pivot">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource PivotBackground}"/>
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Grid/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Pivot">
                <Grid x:Name="RootElement" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}">
                    <Grid.Resources>
                        <Style x:Key="BaseContentControlStyle" TargetType="ContentControl">
                            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="XamlAutoFontFamily"/>
                            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="SemiBold"/>
                            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15"/>
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContentControl">
                                        <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" OpticalMarginAlignment="TrimSideBearings" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                        <Style x:Key="TitleContentControlStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseContentControlStyle}" TargetType="ContentControl">
                            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource PivotTitleFontFamily}"/>
                            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="{ThemeResource PivotTitleThemeFontWeight}"/>
                            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource PivotTitleFontSize}"/>
                        </Style>
                    </Grid.Resources>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="Orientation">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Portrait">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="TitleContentControl" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource PivotPortraitThemePadding}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Landscape">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="TitleContentControl" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource PivotLandscapeThemePadding}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="NavigationButtonsVisibility">
                            <VisualState x:Name="NavigationButtonsHidden"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="NavigationButtonsVisible">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="NextButton" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="NextButton" Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsEnabled">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="True"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PreviousButton" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PreviousButton" Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsEnabled">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="True"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="PreviousButtonVisible">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PreviousButton" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PreviousButton" Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsEnabled">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="True"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="NextButtonVisible">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="NextButton" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="NextButton" Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsEnabled">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="True"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="HeaderStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="HeaderDynamic"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="HeaderStatic">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Header" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="StaticHeader" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <ContentControl x:Name="TitleContentControl" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding TitleTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Title}" IsTabStop="False" Margin="{StaticResource PivotPortraitThemePadding}" Style="{StaticResource TitleContentControlStyle}" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                        <Grid.Resources>
                            <ControlTemplate x:Key="NextTemplate" TargetType="Button">
                                <Border x:Name="Root" Background="{ThemeResource PivotNextButtonBackground}" BorderThickness="{ThemeResource PivotNavButtonBorderThemeThickness}" BorderBrush="{ThemeResource PivotNextButtonBorderBrush}">
                                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Root" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource PivotNextButtonBackgroundPointerOver}"/>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Root" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource PivotNextButtonBorderBrushPointerOver}"/>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Arrow" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource PivotNextButtonForegroundPointerOver}"/>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </VisualState>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Root" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource PivotNextButtonBackgroundPressed}"/>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Root" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource PivotNextButtonBorderBrushPressed}"/>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Arrow" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource PivotNextButtonForegroundPressed}"/>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </VisualState>
                                        </VisualStateGroup>
                                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                    <FontIcon x:Name="Arrow" FontFamily="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}" Foreground="{ThemeResource PivotNextButtonForeground}" FontSize="12" Glyph="&#xE0E3;" HorizontalAlignment="Center" MirroredWhenRightToLeft="True" UseLayoutRounding="False" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                </Border>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                            <ControlTemplate x:Key="PreviousTemplate" TargetType="Button">
                                <Border x:Name="Root" Background="{ThemeResource PivotPreviousButtonBackground}" BorderThickness="{ThemeResource PivotNavButtonBorderThemeThickness}" BorderBrush="{ThemeResource PivotPreviousButtonBorderBrush}">
                                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Root" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource PivotPreviousButtonBackgroundPointerOver}"/>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Root" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource PivotPreviousButtonBorderBrushPointerOver}"/>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Arrow" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource PivotPreviousButtonForegroundPointerOver}"/>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </VisualState>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Root" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource PivotPreviousButtonBackgroundPressed}"/>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Root" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource PivotPreviousButtonBorderBrushPressed}"/>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Arrow" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource PivotPreviousButtonForegroundPressed}"/>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </VisualState>
                                        </VisualStateGroup>
                                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                    <FontIcon x:Name="Arrow" FontFamily="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}" Foreground="{ThemeResource PivotPreviousButtonForeground}" FontSize="12" Glyph="&#xE0E2;" HorizontalAlignment="Center" MirroredWhenRightToLeft="True" UseLayoutRounding="False" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                </Border>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Grid.Resources>
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer" BringIntoViewOnFocusChange="False" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" HorizontalSnapPointsAlignment="Center" HorizontalSnapPointsType="MandatorySingle" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Template="{StaticResource ScrollViewerScrollBarlessTemplate}" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalSnapPointsType="None" VerticalScrollMode="Disabled" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ZoomMode="Disabled">
                            <PivotPanel x:Name="Panel" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                                <Grid x:Name="PivotLayoutElement">
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.RenderTransform>
                                        <CompositeTransform x:Name="PivotLayoutElementTranslateTransform"/>
                                    </Grid.RenderTransform>
                                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="LeftHeaderPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding LeftHeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding LeftHeader}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                                    <ContentControl x:Name="HeaderClipper" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" UseSystemFocusVisuals="True">
                                        <ContentControl.Clip>
                                            <RectangleGeometry x:Name="HeaderClipperGeometry"/>
                                        </ContentControl.Clip>
                                        <Grid Background="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderBackground}">
                                            <Grid.RenderTransform>
                                                <CompositeTransform x:Name="HeaderOffsetTranslateTransform"/>
                                            </Grid.RenderTransform>
                                            <PivotHeaderPanel x:Name="StaticHeader" Visibility="Collapsed">
                                                <PivotHeaderPanel.RenderTransform>
                                                    <CompositeTransform x:Name="StaticHeaderTranslateTransform"/>
                                                </PivotHeaderPanel.RenderTransform>
                                            </PivotHeaderPanel>
                                            <PivotHeaderPanel x:Name="Header">
                                                <PivotHeaderPanel.RenderTransform>
                                                    <CompositeTransform x:Name="HeaderTranslateTransform"/>
                                                </PivotHeaderPanel.RenderTransform>
                                            </PivotHeaderPanel>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </ContentControl>
                                    <Button x:Name="PreviousButton" Background="Transparent" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="36" IsEnabled="False" IsTabStop="False" Margin="{ThemeResource PivotNavButtonMargin}" Opacity="0" Template="{StaticResource PreviousTemplate}" UseSystemFocusVisuals="False" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="20"/>
                                    <Button x:Name="NextButton" Background="Transparent" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="36" IsEnabled="False" IsTabStop="False" Margin="{ThemeResource PivotNavButtonMargin}" Opacity="0" Template="{StaticResource NextTemplate}" UseSystemFocusVisuals="False" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="20"/>
                                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="RightHeaderPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding RightHeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding RightHeader}" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                                    <ItemsPresenter x:Name="PivotItemPresenter" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="1">
                                        <ItemsPresenter.RenderTransform>
                                            <TransformGroup>
                                                <TranslateTransform x:Name="ItemsPresenterTranslateTransform"/>
                                                <CompositeTransform x:Name="ItemsPresenterCompositeTransform"/>
                                            </TransformGroup>
                                        </ItemsPresenter.RenderTransform>
                                    </ItemsPresenter>
                                </Grid>
                            </PivotPanel>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: @Micheael Puckett II I have a question about the second part of your answer, though. If I make my `style` doesn't it apply to all my `pivots` how can I customize the colors then?

Comment: You make a new ```Style``` for each ```PivotItem``` and reference the correct ```Style``` for each one. Note:  You don't have to redo the entire style... use the style's ```BaseOn``` property to chain them and make only the changes you need.

Comment: Oh, ok. But that's a little bit too much of a work to define all styles separately. Thx for the answer once again ;).